# Is my assumption about dependencies for this particular setup correct?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a list of positive, whole numbers $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_q$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $0 \le n_k < m$ for $k = 1, 2, \cdots, q$, let $T$ be the set of all possible tuples $\left(t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_q\right)$ with $0\le t_k \le n_k$ for $k = 1, 2, \cdots, q$ and $\sum^{q}_{i=1}{\left(t_i\right)}=m$. Based on examples it seems that $\vert T \vert$ depends only on $m$ and $\sum^{q}_{i=1}{\left(n_i\right)}$.

To give such an example:

$$m=4,n_1=2,n_2=3,n_3=1\\ T_A = \{ \begin{array} \\ \left(2,2,0\right),\left(1,3,0\right),\left(2,1,1\right),\left(1,2,1\right),\left(0,3,1\right) \end{array} \}$$

now

$$m=4,n_1=2,n_2=2,n_3=2\\ T_B = \{ \begin{array} \\ \left(2,2,0\right),\left(0,2,2\right),\left(2,1,1\right),\left(1,2,1\right),\left(1,1,2\right) \end{array} \}$$

$\rightarrow \vert T_A \vert = \vert T_B \vert$

Comment: With $m=4$, for $(3,3,3)$ I get $|T|=12$ and for $(2,3,4)$ I get $|T|=11$.

Comment: Sorry, should've added that $0 \le n_k < m$

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent to the number of solutions of 
\begin{equation}
x_1+\dots +x_q=m
\end{equation}
where $0\le x_i \le n_k$ for every $1\le i \le q$

- Total number of unrestricted solutions is $\binom{m+q-1}{q-1}$
- Number of solutions of the equation $x_1+\dots +x_q=m$ where exactly $r$ of the $x_i$'s exceed their limit is $\sum_{i=1}^{\binom{q}{r}}\binom{m-(r+S(r,i))+q-1}{q-1}$ where $S(r,i)$ is the sum of the $i$ th (in some predefined canonical order) $r$-subset of $\{n_1,n_2,\dots ,n_q\}$

By inclusion-exclusion theorem,
$$\binom{m+q-1}{q-1} - q -\sum_{r=1}^{q}(-1)^r \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\binom{q}{r}}\binom{m-(r+S(r,i))+q-1}{q-1} \right)$$

$q$ is subtracted to remove the cases when exactly one $x_i=m$ and the rest are zero.

Comment: What exactly is equivalent to the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots +x_q=m$?

Comment: equivalent to $\mid T \mid$

Comment: talegari: Its hard to follow your answer due to those incomplete sentences. However, it doesn't seem to be an answer to my question anyway, as I'm not seeking for a function giving me the amount of solutions, I want to know if the amount stays the same if you change $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_q$ accordingly.